# Babylon.js camera rotation via keyboard control

Tags: camera, keyboard, babylonjs

In Babylon.js, is it possible to control the camera's rotation via keyboard (this is for a space based shooter)?

The only control seems to apply to position: .keysUp, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Babylon's ArcRotateCamera can be rotated using the keyboard, but it might not fit your use-case. If it does, problem solved :) . if not:

Babylon.js allows you to fully configure your inputs. The input system of the cameras allow you to develop your own rotation and position methods and integrate it with your camera. You can read all about it here - http://doc.babylonjs.com/tutorials/customizing_camera_inputs

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. For now, I'm using pointerlock. I'll look into keyboard control in due course.